# Check matching data in Dataframes in spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

How can i match if two RDD generated the way i did contains the same data including number of rows?
I'm using scala test to run the tests and spark version 3 with scala 2.12.12
Below my code from the creation of the schemas of my two rdd, included the expected one and the creation of all 3 rdd with data.

```
-- CREATING SCHEMA FOR RDD AMOUNTS AND WAREHOUSE AND EXPECTED FINAL SCHEMA

  val amountsSchema: StructType = StructType(
    Seq(
      StructField("positionId", LongType, nullable = true),
      StructField("amount", DecimalType(10, 2), nullable = true),
      StructField("eventTime",LongType, nullable = true),
    )
  )

  val warehouseSchema: StructType = StructType(
    Seq(
      StructField("positionId", LongType, nullable = true),
      StructField("warehouse", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("product", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("eventTime",LongType, nullable = true),
    )
  )

  val expectedDfSchema: StructType = StructType(
    Seq(
      StructField("positionId", LongType, nullable = true),
      StructField("warehouse", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("product", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("amount", DecimalType(10, 2), nullable = true),
    )
  )

--- CREATING DATA FOR RDD AMOUNTS RDD AND WAREHOUSE RDD AND EXPECTED FINAL RDD

  val amounts_data = Seq(
    Row("1", "5.00", "1528463387"),
    Row("1", "7.20", "1528463005"),
    Row("2", "5.00", "1528463097"),
    Row("2", "7.20", "1528463007"),
    Row("3", "6.00", "1528463078"),
    Row("4", "24.20", "1528463008"),
    Row("4", "15.00", "1528463100"),
  )


  val wh_data = Seq(
    Row("1", "W-1", "P-1", "1528463098"),
    Row("2", "W-2", "P-2", "1528463097"),
    Row("3", "W-2", "P-3", "1528463078"),
    Row("4", "W-1", "P-6", "1528463100"),
  )

  val expected_data = Seq(
    Row("1", "W-1", "P-1", "5.00"),
    Row("2", "W-2", "P-2", "5.00"),
    Row("3", "W-2", "P-3", "6.00"),
    Row("4", "W-1", "P-6", "15.00")
  )

---- CREATING RDD WITH SCHEMAS AND DATA FOR DF_AMOUNTS AND DF_WAREHOUSE AND FOR THE EXPECTED RDD WITH EXPECTED_DATA

  val df_amounts: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(amounts_data),
    amountsSchema
  )

  val df_wh: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(wh_data),
    warehouseSchema
  )

  val df_expected: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(expected_data),
    expectedDfSchema
  )

---- USING GET_AMOUNTS METHOD TO GENERATE A RDD FROM THE FUNCTION get_amounts



  val resDf: DataFrame = get_amounts(df_amounts, df_wh)



---- TESTING IF THE resDf SCHEMA MATCH WITH THE EXPECTED SCHEMA - IT DOES TEST PASSED

  test("DataFrame Schema Test") {
    assert(assertSchema(resDf.schema, df_expected.schema))
  }

---- TESTING IF THE resDf DATA MATCH WITH THE EXPECTED DATA - IT DOESNT'T MATCH
  test("DataFrame Data Test") {
    assert(assertData(resDf, df_expected))
  }
}
```

The assertData function used to match the data for the expected data rdd and the one coming from my function get_amounts but it fails the test.

```
def assertData(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame): Boolean = {
    df1.exceptAll(df2).rdd.isEmpty()
  }
```

Thank You

Comment: chg title to dataframes.

Comment: Ok i have don't the changing thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you create a datasets is valid. A test structure looks good as well.
I would suggest to improve your assert method to see why the test case failes, here you can find some thoughts on your testing method:

- `exceptAll` is not a perfect for testing, if the `df2` contains an additional row it will still say that the data matches, consider below code:

```scala
  val df1 = Seq(
    (1, "x"),
    (2, "y")
  ).toDF("x", "y")
  
  val df2 = Seq(
    (1, "x"),
    (2, "y"),
    (3, "z")
  ).toDF("x", "y")
  
  assert(df1.exceptAll(df2).rdd.isEmpty())
```

- *"this function resolves columns by position (not by name)"* (from Spark code scala docs), due to this sometimes you can get confused about your test result.
- your assert method says nothing about what exactly mismatched

For testing purposes is not bad to collect (small amount of) data and match sequences.
You can consider using a method like this one:

```scala
  def matchDF(resultDF: DataFrame, expectedDF: DataFrame): Unit = {
    resultDF.printSchema()
    expectedDF.printSchema()
    assert(resultDF.schema == expectedDF.schema, 
        s"Schema does not match: ${resultDF.schema} != ${expectedDF.schema}")
    val expected = expectedDF.collect().toSeq
    val result = resultDF.collect().toSeq
    assert(expected == result, s"Data does not match: $result != $expected")
  }
```

It's not a perfect approach (still depends on the position in a row), but at least you will be able to find out what is going on and why your test fails.

For wrong data you'll see this:

```
assertion failed: Data does not match: WrappedArray([1,x], [2,y]) != WrappedArray([1,x], [3,y])
```

For wrong schema you'll get:

```
root
 |-- x: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Schema does not match
```

I hope this will help you understand what is going wrong.